# Authenticate users syncing time out for 2 different sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have been puzzling over this and can't think of an good way of doing this. I am developing a website that would require the user to log in to use the system. I'm thinking of using ASP.NET MVC 4's built in authentication. That isn't much of a problem.

The user would be able to use tools on another server (our server would authenticate him and tell the other website, he is good to go, these messages are passed via HTTPS using XML). The other server, require us to create an authentication token for the user to use when the messages are passed between us.

We need to keep the token in our database to authenticate for every request/response with the other server. Which means that this "token table" knows nothing about the forms authentication time out on our server and vice-verse.

Now the problem, let's say the user uses the other server's tools. He would be on the other server for a long time, this would cause the authentication on our server to log him out, since there doesn't seem to be any perceived activity. The other server will not log him out since we are manually maintaining the token. This would be a troublesome for the user, because now, if he needs to use our service, he'll have to log in again even though he was "online" all the time.

Is there a way to "sync" the 2 authentications? At first I was thinking of getting our server to look up the "token table" (instead of using the built in authentication) so that if the last activity was x ago, the user will be required to log in again, this would solve the untimely logging out from our server. But I'm worried about the security implications.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Desmond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you are using [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) in an MVC4 application to authenticate users, but users will also use another web service located on a different server and so while they are using this other server you don't want the MVC4 application's authentication (for the user) to timeout. Is that correct?

If so, one idea that comes to mind is that your MVC4 application could have an API to the external world that would take in a username and use [RenewTicketIfOld()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.renewticketifold.aspx) to refresh the timer associated with the ticket. You could do this via the other web server making an HTTP request or by simply placing some AJAX on the page to call the API on every page.

There are, of course, security concerns with this method that you would need to consider. Without knowing more about your situation I'm not sure what solution would be best.

Comment: Thanks Rowan. You have understood the problem perfectly. What security concerns are there in using the method you outlined above?

Comment: Just that you would be sending a username over the wire. Maybe not a big deal, especially if you're already using SSL. You could also encrypt it or hash it. Just things to consider. You could also send a ticket or something instead of a username to be safer.